# Get the descendants of a member

Tags: ssas, mdx

This request always displays '1' in the column 'nb', but I know that for this patient, the number is '3':

```
WITH
member pat1 AS [DimTransfusion].[TransfusionPatients].[PatientId].&[{09B7106A-xxxx-4B88-80D6-D1283FE990D6}]--83
set transfusPat AS Descendants(pats1,2)
MEMBER nb AS count(transfusPat)
SELECT {nb} ON 0
FROM [BDD PBM]
```

but this request displays the correct result:

```
WITH
member pat1 AS [DimTransfusion].[TransfusionPatients].[PatientId].&[{09B7106A-xxxx-4B88-80D6-D1283FE990D6}]--83
set transfusPat AS Descendants([DimTransfusion].[TransfusionPatients].[PatientId].&[{09B7106A-FB68-4B88-80D6-D1283FE990D6}],2)
MEMBER nb AS count(transfusPat)
SELECT {nb} ON 0
FROM [BDD PBM]
```

I can't understand why using a member variable instead a real value gives a wrong result.

Here is the dimension usage screenshot:

[image: dimension usage]

where VPARCOURS and VTRANSFUSION are fact tables(a Transfusion is always related to one VPARCOURS):

[image: diagram]

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to pat1: being a member, I suppose the Descendants function returns a member of its first argument is a member, and the same for sets:
so the correct declaration is:

```
set pat1 AS [DimTransfu...
```